# ZingChart X-axis labels showing as numbers instead of strings

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, zingchart

I am using the ZingChart library to graph results from an API call. When I pass in a normal array for the "values" field of the chart data object, everything works fine. However, when I pass in an array made from `Object.keys(titleSet)` (where `titleSet` is a normal Javascript object), the graph displays as follows:

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nCQH.png)

As you can see, the x-axis is now labeled with numbers instead of the array of strings. But when I print out the the result of `Object.keys(titleSet)` vs. passing in a normal array, they both appear to be the same in the console. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
//List of movies inputted by the user
var movieList = [];
var movieSet = {};

var IMDBData = {
  "values": [], 
  "text": "IMDB",
};
var metascoreData = {
  "values": [], 
  "text": "Metascore"
};
var RTMData = {
  "values": [], 
  "text": "Rotten Tomatoes Meter"
};
var RTUData = {
  "values": [],
   "text": "Rotten Tomatoes User"
};

var chartData = { 
  "type":"bar",
  "legend":{
    "adjust-layout": true
  },
  "plotarea": {
    "adjust-layout":true
  },
  "plot":{ 
    "stacked": true,
    "border-radius": "1px",
    "tooltip": {
      "text": "Rated %v by %plot-text"
    },
    "animation":{
      "effect":"11",
      "method":"3",
      "sequence":"ANIMATION_BY_PLOT_AND_NODE",
      "speed":10
    } 
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "label":{ /* Scale Title */
      "text":"Movie Title",
    },
    "values": Object.keys(movieSet) /* Needs to be list of movie titles */
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "label":{ /* Scale Title */
      "text":"Total Score",
    }
  },
  "series":[metascoreData, IMDBData, RTUData, RTMData]
};


var callback = function(data)
{
  var resp = JSON.parse(data);

  movieSet[resp.Title] = true;

  //Render
  zingchart.render({ 
    id:'chartDiv',
    data:chartData,
  });
};
```

Comment: Typically it would be very useful for us to post the graph configuration before and after. Please post your code to get a more solidified answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to include my configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full Disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

Thank you for updating your question. The problem is you have defined your variable `movieSet` before the variable`chartData`. When parsing the page, top down, it is executing Object.keys({}) on an empty object when creating the variable `chartData`. You should just directly assign it into your config later on `chartData['scale-x']['values'] = Object.keys(moviSet)`.

```
var callback = function(data)
{
  var resp = JSON.parse(data);

  movieSet[resp.Title] = true;

  //Render
  zingchart.render({ 
    id:'chartDiv',
    data:chartData,
  });
};
```

There is a problem with the above code as well. It seems you are calling render on the chart every time you call this API. You should have one initial `zingchart.render()` and then from there on out use our [API](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/api-methods/). I would suggest `setdata` method as it replaces a whole new JSON packet or `modify` method.

I am making some assumptions on how you are handling data. Regardless, check out the following demo

```js
var movieValues = {};

var myConfig = {
  type: "bar", 
  scaleX:{
    values:[]
  },
 series : [
  {
   values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 300, 
 width: '100%' 
});

var callback = function(data) {
  movieValues[data.title] = true;
  myConfig.scaleX.values = Object.keys(movieValues);
  zingchart.exec('myChart', 'setdata', {
    data:myConfig
  })
}

var index = 0;
var movieNamesFromDB = ['Sausage Party', 'Animal House', 'Hot Rod', 'Blazing Saddles'];
setInterval(function() {
  if (index < 4) {
    callback({title:movieNamesFromDB[index++]});
  }
},1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
</script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you noticed in the demo, the length of `scaleX.values` determines how many nodes are shown on the graph. If you change `values` to `labels` this wont happen.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks for the help and advice, this is my first time using ZingCharts :)